# Python 2.7 Descriptor -- What is "Binding Behavior"

Tags: python-2.7, descriptor

In the Python 2.7 documentation on Descriptors in the [Introduction](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) the phrase *binding behavior* is used.

> In general, a descriptor is an object attribute with “binding behavior”, one whose attribute access has been overridden by methods in the descriptor protocol. Those methods are **get**(), **set**(), and **delete**(). If any of those methods are defined for an object, it is said to be a descriptor.

I am seeking a clear explanation of "binding behavior?" Is the word "one" referring to the word object? If that is the case then a descriptor is an object attribute that has been overridden by methods in a descriptor. Seems to be a recursive definition. Is binding behavior the ability to be assigned to an object member?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just recently was reading the same article you were. And while I am almost a year late, I believe what it means is a developer can define behavior and then bind it to a given property. In respect to descriptors, this basically means binding the way a value can be set, queried or deleted for a given variable/object/data set. This interaction is 'bound' to this piece of data as in it only applies to what data you've set it on.